# How to set the font generated from a beamer latex file to Times New Roman?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, beamer

How to set the font generated from a beamer latex file to Times New Roman in preamble?

Thanks!

Comment: @user376089 If you feel a submitted answer is correct please click the grey "✓" beside it.

Comment: No grey "✓", up vote or even thank you from him it seems....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html, choose the most similar font to the one you want and add

```
\includepackage{fontname}
```

in the preamble

you can try also with `\includepackage{times}` but I don't know if it's the font you want..

Answer (score 3):

The times package is obsolete. Better use mathptmx with Times Roman as default text font and supporting math as well:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

Btw. the default warnings (including font warning) would appear with Times as well. To get rid of it see [Removing beamer warnings](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/presentations/beamer-warnings/).